# Azure function: After zip deploy, there is not function in the function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

This is the structure of the azure function:

```
john1@MacBook-Pro:~/myapp/code/acme$ tree azure_function -L 3 -I node_modules
azure_function
├── host.json
├── jest.config.ts
├── local.settings.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── functions
│       ├── acmeWorkerFunctionDevjohn1.ts
│       ├── constants
│       ├── errors
│       ├── interfaces
│       ├── services
│       ├── utils
│       └── worker.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

I made the zip file with this:

```
 zip -r azure_function.zip azure_function
```

The zip deployment was successful:

```
john1@MacBook-Pro:~/myapp/code/acme$ az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g acmeworkerdevjohn1 -n acmeWorkerFunction1Devjohn1 --src azure_function.zip
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
{
  "active": true,
  "author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "Push-Deployer",
  "end_time": "2023-08-01T05:06:33.0557935Z",
  "id": "a93f9763-f927-4686-983d-d9dfbe9993e2",
  "is_readonly": true,
  "is_temp": false,
  "last_success_end_time": "2023-08-01T05:06:33.0557935Z",
  "log_url": "https://acmeworkerfunction1devjohn1.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
  "message": "Created via a push deployment",
  "progress": "",
  "received_time": "2023-08-01T05:04:46.8686012Z",
  "site_name": "acmeworkerfunction1devjohn1",
  "start_time": "2023-08-01T05:04:49.346347Z",
  "status": 4,
  "status_text": "",
  "url": "https://acmeworkerfunction1devjohn1.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
}
```

However, after deployment, in Azure portal, there is no functions in function app.

Why is the function not appearing in the functions blade in the portal?

Answer (score 0):

**I deployed my Azure function using the command:**

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <Resource_Group_Name> -n <function_app_name> --src <zip_file_path_of_function_project>
```

[image]

- But I couldn't see the function in *functionapp* in *Portal* as you mentioned:

[image]

**I added below settings in Function App=> Settings=>Configuration=> Add New Application Settings:**

```
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1
```

[image]

- Deployed the Azure function again:

[image]

**Portal:**

I can see the deployed function in Portal:

[image]